# How to make ActFramework look for template from a different root folder when user is requesting using a specific locale

Tags: java, model-view-controller, frameworks, internationalization, actframework

I am trying to i18n my application and I have the default template files sit under `resources/rythm` folder. However I also have a corresponding template files for Chinese language sit inside `resources/rythm/cn` dir, how can I make Act look for the Chinese versions inside that dir?

Comment: Note this question is posted by ActFramework author in order to create the `actframework` tag, I will answer this question later on

Comment: Please compare the link related to that with that on your website. When you click on the Stack overflow link, your website has https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/Act.Framework instead of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actframework

Comment: @TheOracle thank you very much! It's fixed

Answer (score 2):

Creating an app configurator and configure the `act.view.TemplatePathResolver` implementation, and inside it do your trick:

```
public static class MyConfiguration extends AppConfigurator {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        templatePathResolver(new TemplatePathResolver() {
            @Override
            protected String resolveTemplatePath(String path, ActContext context) {
                String resolved = super.resolveTemplatePath(path, context);
                Locale locale = context.locale(true);
                if ("zh".equals(locale.getLanguage())) {
                    resolved = "/cn" + (resolved.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/") + resolved;
                }
                return resolved;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As shown above, my [website](http://actframework.org) supports two locale/languages: Chinese and English, all English version goes to the default path, and all Chinese version goes to the `cn/` path